# Setting catcodes in a group

Tags: catcodes

Can someone explain to my why `\foo` and `\bar` are not the same (in the `\ifx` sense) in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begingroup
  \catcode`|=3\relax
  \gdef\abc{|}
\endgroup
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foobar{
  \begingroup
    \catcode`|=3\relax
    \def\abc{|}
    \@foobar
}
\newcommand\@foobar[1]{
  \xdef\foo{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\edef\bar{\abc}
\foobar{\abc}

\begin{document}
foo means ``\meaning\foo'' and bar means ``\meaning\bar'', but the ``meanings'' are
\ifx\foo\bar
  same
\else
  different
\fi
\end{document}
```

I included the `\@foobar` because I read somewhere that the `catcode` had to be changed before reading the macro parameter (I don't think it applies here, but I have no idea what I am doing).

The global definition of `\abc` (the one defined with `\gdef`) is | with catcode 3. I would like the local definition of `\abc` (the one defined with `\def`) to also be | with catcode 3. In my example the local `\abc` is | with catcode 12. Ultimately I would like to have `\foobar{\abc}` expand to | with catcode 3 without having `\abc` defined golbally.

Comment: You say you want to avoid the global definition of `\abc` but what do you want to define it to be? How do you want to use it? If you edit your question to give some higher level requirements, someone could suggest some code that would help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried to clarify the question. I hope it helps.

Comment: OK I added some code to my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
\newcommand\foobar{
  \begingroup
    \catcode`|=3\relax
    \def\abc{|}
    \@foobar
}
```

The `\def\abc{|}` is read by `\newcommand` and its catcodes are fixed then. The `\catcode`|=3\relax`is executed when the`\foobar` macro is *used* not when it is *defined*.

You can use the following instead:

```
\begingroup
\newcommand\foobar{}% to get the name check 
\catcode`\|=3\relax
\gdef\foobar{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\|=3\relax
    \def\abc{|}%
    \@foobar
}
\endgroup
```

This changes the catcode of `|` to 3 also for the definition. You onlt need to use `\@foobar` if the user should be allowed to add `|` with catcode 3 inside the argument. Otherwise you simply let `\foobar` read the argument and use `\xdef\foo{#1}` inside `\foobar` directly. Then you don't need the second, inner`\catcode`\|=3\relax` line as well.

Also, you should place `%` at lines ending with `{` or `}` because otherwise the source code line breaks will be taken as a space which are inserted in the document.

Comment: I think there is an extra `\begingroup` in the definition of `\foobar` (left over from my awful example). I am not so confident to actually edit your answer.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: No, I don't think so. The closing `\endgroup` is inside `\@foobar`. Keep in mind that the outer grouping commands are executed during the definition but the inner ones during the usage of the macro.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea what you want to achieve. But the catcode of an input is assigned at the moment when TeX *reads* the input the first time. When the definition body of foobar is read the catcode of | is "other" and so your `\foobar` will always define "`\abc` = `| with catcode other`", regardless of the catcode value when you actually execute `\foobar`.

If you want to change the catcode of an input you can do it e.g. by writing it to an external file and then reinput it or by using `\scantokens`.

Answer (score 4):

They are different because one holds a math-shift character and the other holds a punctuation character (catcodes 3 and 12) you can see this if you typeset

```
foo \foo 1*2*3 \foo

bar \bar 1*2*3 \bar
```

You can locally define `\abc` to be a `\catcode 3` `|` with various idioms for example this one is used all over the place (usually with `~` to get an active character rather than `$`) for example the definition of `\verb` in latex.ltx.

```
\begingroup\lccode`$=`\|\lowercase{\endgroup\def\abc{$}}
```

defines `\abc` to be a math-shift `|` without any global definition.